# The most popular LaTeX logos and personalize a \guit logo

Tags: color, logos

With this question I was wondering what are the most popular commands that enable me to write logos using LaTeX code (for example I know only `\LaTeX`, `\TeX` and `\guit`),

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{guit}
\begin{document}
\LaTeX, \TeX, \guit[color]
\end{document}
```

and if I use the command `\guit` from `guit` package, I can change each letter (`g`, `u`, `i`, `t`) with letters that I like, like my name, different colors of my choice keeping the same structure of the characters.

**EDIT:**
Is it possible to build my personal logo using the `guit` or `hologo` package (see the answer by @Mensch) only from one command (for example `\guit[color]{SeBAstiano})`?

Comment: Automating that for arbitrary strings (or even fonts) seems almost impossible, as you'd have to know about the shape of the individual letters (which TeX doesn't, as far as I know) to not get unpleasant "gaps" in the final output. For example, in your name it would make a difference in kerning if you'd use `ba` or `BA` when the 'a'/'A' is pushed up. The lowercase letters would have to be put a bit closer together.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should have a look to package `hologo` on [ctan](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/hologo) and the [documentation](http://vesta.informatik.rwth-aachen.de/ftp/pub/mirror/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/oberdiek/hologo.pdf) there. Have a look into the toc:

[image]

showing some of the known logos in `hologo` ... See the documentation for a complete list of supported logos for LaTeX and friends ...

Comment: I use them so little that when I saw your image I remembered, to be honest, others :-). But could I make a custom one with my name on it? :-). Thank you so much  much for your answer.

Comment: @Sebastiano You can try to use the commands for kerning and raising letters used in Heiko Oberdieks package to define your own logo. Then you can also change the color of a letter, but be aware that that could be a time consuming process until you get a result looking really pretty ...

Comment: Hi, I edited my question. I hope now is clearer. I understood your comment very well but I didn't want to create my own logo using the kerning of characters. I thought that you could do something directly by writing my name and automatically comes out my name with the same style.

Comment: @Sebastiano Sorry, was offline. I do nou understand italian, so I can not understand the description for `guit.sty`.  But the problem is the same: How should `SeBAstiano` be changed into a logo? For `\LaTeX` the design is well defined, but not for `SeBAstiano` ... So you need to define that by your own to get a pretty logo, playing with (colors; do you really need them?) and different combination of up- or downraised letters or lettergroups. That can only do you. You can use the same commands used for `\LaTeX`, but you will have to play with the values. Then you can define an own command

Comment: @Sebastiano `\Sebastiano` to display your own logo, using the commands you had to play with before ...

Comment: I always thank you with all my heart for your kindness, helpfulness and elegance in your comments. I was thinking of finishing the 11th of June with the school and instead I was appointed to the state exams in a school in my country that I tremendously can't tolerate as citizens. I cross my fingers. Thank you very much and my best regards.